# ZXing and Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing

I've got a question for anyone who's worked with the ZXING barcode scanner in Xamarin.

I've got an app that has one page with the following code:

```
<zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="TicketScanView"
 OnScanResult="Ticket_OnScanResult"
 IsEnabled="False"
 IsScanning="False"
 WidthRequest="350"
 HeightRequest="300"
 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

Everything works great on Android and IPhone.
However when I add a second page with the same ZXing definition but change the name, the app runs on the iPhone and crashes on Android.
Any ideas/suggestions/input would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What exception causes the crash?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: I'm not getting a stack trace. When I try to run to debug the app through Visual Studio only a black screen is displayed which is obviously a separate problem. So, when I just run the app on the android it crashes

Comment: Have you checked the device logs?  Have you tried adding exception handling to the suspect code?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it is something to do with the first page not releasing resources when your second scanner page tries to access things but without any logs or a stack trace we have nothing to go on...